# why does this SQL not work when both fields are included

Tags: mysql, sql

So this first SQL returns zero rows:

```
SELECT b.b_id 
FROM `buy` b 
    INNER JOIN `buy_multiples` AS bm 
        ON b.b_id = bm.b_id 
        AND b.buy_status IN (2)  
WHERE bm.`option_type` = 'area_id'  
AND bm.selected_option_key IN (10)
AND bm.`option_type` = 'bzips'  
AND bm.selected_option_key IN (37027)
GROUP BY b.b_id
```

This second SQL returns b_id 5024 and 4987:

```
SELECT b.b_id 
FROM `buy` b 
    INNER JOIN `buy_multiples` AS bm 
        ON b.b_id = bm.b_id 
        AND b.buy_status IN (2)  
WHERE bm.`option_type` = 'bzips'  
AND bm.selected_option_key IN (37027)
GROUP BY b.b_id
```

This third SQL returns b_id 5024 and 4987 and 4989:

```
SELECT b.b_id 
FROM `buy` b 
    INNER JOIN `buy_multiples` AS bm 
        ON b.b_id = bm.b_id 
        AND b.buy_status IN (2)  
WHERE bm.`option_type` = 'area_id'  
AND bm.selected_option_key IN (10)
GROUP BY b.b_id
```

Why the first one returns zero rows?

Comment: Something does not look right here. How come 5024 comes in both queries 2 and 3?? What is its `option_type` value? Are you sure you are running the queries in the same DB?

Comment: Check this Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1222e/4 . Run queries one by one, your 1st query works fine...

Comment: you are correct. I screwed up the first query. the OR was left over from my debugging. It was suppose to be an AND

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first query, you're looking for any records where `bm.option_type = 'area_id'`
AND `bm.option_type = 'bzips'`.  This will always return 0 results.  You want to use:

```
SELECT b.b_id 
FROM `buy` b 
    INNER JOIN `buy_multiples` AS bm 
        ON b.b_id = bm.b_id 
        AND b.buy_status IN (2)  
WHERE bm.`option_type` = 'area_id'  
AND bm.selected_option_key IN (10)
OR bm.`option_type` = 'bzips'  
AND bm.selected_option_key IN (37027)
GROUP BY b.b_id
```

Comment: ic3b3rg,thanks
so i was thinking that the () was going to contain
so any ideas if i want to find where 
(bm.option_type = 'area_id' AND bm.selected_option_key IN (10)) 
AND 
(bm.option_type = 'bzips' AND bm.selected_option_key IN (37027)

the table has
b_id, option_type and selected_option_key

Comment: you're missing the point... the WHERE clause is evaluated for each record.  The entire clause must be True for a record to be included in the results.  Using AND with the two values of option_type doesn't make sense.  You're basically saying you want to find records with two values of option_type stored, which isn't possible.

Comment: Unfortunately i follow, thanks for your help.
i am just trying to figure out how I can do this. I think i may have a fault in the way i designed this table.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're after something like this...

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.b_id 
  FROM buy b 
  JOIN buy_multiples bm 
    ON bm.b_id = b.b_id 
 WHERE b.buy_status IN (2)  
   AND (
        (bm.option_type = 'area_id' AND bm.selected_option_key IN (10)) 
     OR (bm.option_type = 'bzips' AND bm.selected_option_key IN (37027))
       );
```